# Given an array of digits & characters, find the longest continuous subarray with equal numbers of both

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Lets assume that an array is given, and you have to find the longest continuous subarray that contains the same amount of characters and digits. For example we have an array of chars like ('a',0,'v',2,4,7,'e','f','b',2,5,2,1).

In that case the longest subarray would be ('v',2,4,7,'e','f','b',2), because it would be 4 characters and 4 digits.

I have solved similar problems like the 'maximum contiguous subarray problem', but i just can't wrap my head around this one. Also if this is a well known problem, what is the best-case solution to it? Is it possible to solve it with the time complexity of O(n)?

Comment: O(1) ist obviously impossible. Did you mean O(n)?

Comment: O(1) means no matter how many elements are in the array it takes the same amount of effort to process. Since you can't make any judgement about the contents of a random array without looking at each element, O(1) can be taken off the table immediately.

Comment: I'm going to tell you right now it's impossible to solve this in any less than O(n). Especially since you have no information of the order of the array, you'll need to look at each element at least once.

Comment: a,0,v,2,4,7,e,f,b,2 has 5 digits and 5 chars. Just saying

Comment: First step is to compute the number of chars and ints to the left and right of each position, in O(n)

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yes, typo i was thinking about O(n).

Comment: @JeffreysupportsMonica You are right. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the range [x,y] has the same number of ints as chars, then the range [0,x] and [0,y] has the same value for (num ints) - (num chars). We can use this to calculate the answer in linear time, linear space, by maintaining a hash of the cumulative differences in ints vs chars.

1. Maintain a hash, initially empty, that will map the delta of the counts to 
   an index. (#ints - #chars). E.g., 7->22 indicates that a delta of 7 was
   first seen at index 22.
2. Keep track of `longest_length` (initially 0) and `start_index` (initially nil)
3. Parse the array, keeping track of the counts of ints & chars.
4. Calculate the difference. Check your hash. If it exists in the hash, 
   compare the difference in indices to your `longest_length` and 
   update appropriately. If it doesn't, update the hash.

At the end of this, the answer is `[start_index, start_index + longest_length]`.

Comment: I think this works. But the hash should initially map delta `0` to index `-1`.

Comment: @Dave Yes this should work, but how do i keep track of the start_index variable?

Comment: @JozefNagy In step 4. E.g., say at index 22 you have a delta of 7 for the first time, so h[7]=22. Then at index 100 you also have a delta of 7. When you check your hash, you see that there was also a delta of 7 at index 22. If 100 - 22 = 78 is your new longest length, then you update longest_length=78 and start_index=22.